# Does unencrypted file on S3 bucket have Etag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etag

Process of centralizing a large number of unencrypted small files from multiple Amazon S3 buckets. Can the integrity of these files be tested with Etags?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

I read this above document. But unclear on unencrypted files on S3. Can someone verify on this?

Comment: What do you mean by `integrity of these files`? To validate if the files are the same in multiple buckets?

Answer (score 1):

From AWS [doc on S3 data integrity](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) :

The entity tag (ETag) is a hash of the object that might not be an MD5 digest of the object data. Whether the ETag is an MD5 digest depends on how the object was created and encrypted. Because the ETag isn't always an MD5 digest, it can't always be used for verifying the integrity of uploaded files.

You can read through the doc to get info on how to get MD5 checksum value of the object.

Another article on S3 ETags that could be useful
https://teppen.io/2018/06/23/aws_s3_etags/